# Cannot retrieve EAV product data

Tags: eav, enterprise-1.14, ecomdev-phpunit, unit-tests, phpunit

I'm facing a strange issue (on Magento EE 1.14.2.1) where I cannot retrieve EAV product data after setting up a fixture.

My test:

```
/**
 * @loadFixture
 */
public function testExample()
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
    var_dump($product->getSku(), $product->getData('name'), $product->getPrice());
    exit;
}
```

My fixture:

```
# File: fixtures/testExample.yaml
eav:
    catalog_product:
        - entity_id: 1
          sku: 12345/RED/
          name: Some configurable
          attribute_set_id: 4
          entity_type_id: 4
          type_id: configurable
          price: 49.99
```

I'm using `exit` to prevent EcomDev_PHPUnit from clearing the database tables after the test completes. At the moment my output from this is:

```
string(10) "12345/RED/"
NULL
NULL
```

I can access the product data (e.g. `sku`) that is stored in `catalog_product_entity`, but nothing from the EAV tables.

I've examined the database after this fixture is loaded, and the attributes for example name and price all exist in their respective EAV tables (`catalog_product_entity_varchar` and `catalog_product_entity_decimal`).

The attributes exist in the test database and are configured correctly for the product entity ID and attribute set.

When using `getData()` or `getName()` for example, they always return null.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Incidentally, if I load this product within a collection the name displays correctly the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to re-iterate, my symptoms were:

- If I `->load(1)` the product I only get the values that exist in `catalog_product_entity`
- If I `->setId(1)->load()` I only get the EAV attribute values, not the main table values
- If I run a collection and `->getFirstItem()` with an entity ID filter on it, I get all attributes

---

After a bit of digging around and examining SQL query logs, I actually found that my `eav_entity_attribute` table in the PHPUnit test database was missing its entries for all core Magento EAV attributes. This table is generally not written to or deleted from when running EcomDev PHPUnit tests, unless you have an attribute installer script, or you **fixture this table**.

My assumption is that at some point I had created a fixture for this table which would have cleared the table, and it would never have been regenerated.

I've refreshed this table from my main Magento database and everything works now.

If anybody else comes into this same problem, my quick fix was to run the following SQL query:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
# Refresh the entity attribute records from your main Magento database
TRUNCATE your_unit_test_db.eav_entity_attribute;
INSERT INTO your_unit_test_db.eav_entity_attribute SELECT * FROM your_main_magento_db.eav_entity_attribute;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the product fixture, your initial test setup looks fine.

It's probably the stores fixture that is missing but vital for the EAV data to be loaded correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried with and without a store fixture and the result is the same. If I `->load(123)` I get the main entity table fields, if I `->setId(123)->load()` I get all the EAV fields and not the main ones, and if I load the product with a collection I get all of them (NOT ideal!)